# How can I modify a previously configured StructureMap configuration?

Tags: c#, configuration, structuremap

I have a centralized StructureMap configuration that various user interface applications append to. I have never had the need to modify the "core" configuration only append to it. I've run into an instance today where I need to modify / remove the core configuration for a particular application. Of course I could move the core configuration code out to the different application, but before I do so I wanted to be sure I was not missing something obvious with the StructureMap api. Below is an abbreviated version of my core configuration:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.Assembly("Core");
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();

            scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IValidationRule<>));
            // more after this....
        }
}
```

At runtime for this one application I would like to remove the configuration for types closing `IValidationRule`, but have yet to come up with anything viable. All of the eject methods seem to center around singletons meaning. Since I am not dealing with a singleton the following does not work:

```
ObjectFactory.Model.For(typeof(IValidationRule<>)).EjectAndRemoveAll(); //no work

ObjectFactory.Model.EjectAndRemove(typeof(IValidationRule<>)); //nor does this
```

Is there a way that I can modify my StructureMap configuration to not look for `IValidationRule`s? Can I eject non-singleton instances of `IValidationRule`s? Do I have other options for modifying my StructureMap configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like the following?  I think this should work.

```
ObjectFactory.Model.EjectAndRemoveTypes(match
    => match != null && match.GetInterfaces().Any(i
        => i.Name.Contains("IValidationRule")));
```

Comment: Is something like this possible in StructureMap3 where ObjectFactory has been deprecated?